# Why username and password are not respected in activemq createConnection

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I created a one and only broker in activemq and I am using the following code to produce and consume messages. I took this code [from here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-jms/introduction-to-activemq-artemis).

```
public boolean runExample() throws Exception {
        Connection connection = null;
        InitialContext initialContext = null;
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
            properties.put("connectionFactory.ConnectionFactory", "tcp://localhost:61616");
            properties.put("queue.queue/exampleQueue", "exampleQueue");
            
            initialContext = new InitialContext(properties);
            
            Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("queue/exampleQueue");
            
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("admin", "admin");//brokerone
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("This is a text message");

            System.out.println("Sent message: " + message.getText());
            producer.send(message);
            MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
            connection.start();
            TextMessage messageReceived = (TextMessage) messageConsumer.receive(5000);
            System.out.println("Received message: " + messageReceived.getText());

            return true;
        } finally {
            if (initialContext != null) {
                initialContext.close();
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, while creating connection if I put any random string for password in `connectionFactory.createConnection` method then it still creates connection and I can see the produced messages in broker console. I looked up the [documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactory.html#createConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/ConnectionFactory.html) for more explanation but it also says that the strings passed in createConnection method are username and password.

So now, my question is what is the purpose of username and password when they are not used while creating connection?

Edit1:

broker.xml (after removing bulk commented lines)

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>0.0.0.0</name>
      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>    
      <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>
      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>
      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>
      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>
      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>
      <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>
      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
      <journal-buffer-timeout>1192000</journal-buffer-timeout>
      <!--        When using ASYNCIO, this will determine the writing queue depth for libaio.       -->
      <journal-max-io>1</journal-max-io>     
      <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

      <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols that won't support flow control. -->
      <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

      <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
      <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>      
      <page-sync-timeout>1192000</page-sync-timeout>

      <acceptors>
         <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
         <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
         <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
         <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
         <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
      </acceptors>
      
      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>

      </addresses>
   </core>
</configuration>
```

bootstrap.xml

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.org/schema">

   <jaas-security domain="activemq"/>

   <!-- artemis.URI.instance is parsed from artemis.instance by the CLI startup.
        This is to avoid situations where you could have spaces or special characters on this URI -->
   <server configuration="file:/C:/dev/artemis/apache-artemis-2.13.0/bin/brokerone/etc//broker.xml"/>

   <!-- The web server is only bound to localhost by default -->
   <web bind="http://localhost:8161" path="web">
       <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
       <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
       <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
   </web>


</broker>
```

login.config

```
activemq {
   org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule sufficient
       debug=false
       reload=true
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="artemis-users.properties"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.role="artemis-roles.properties";

   org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.GuestLoginModule sufficient
       debug=false
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.guest.user="admin"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.guest.role="amq";
};
```

Comment: Depending on how your security is configured the broker may simply be allowing any user to connect regardless of what credentials they are using. Can you provide your `bootstrap.xml`, `login.config`, and `broker.xml`?

Comment: Hello Again @JustinBertram, edited the question with requested files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The username and password *are* used when creating the connection. The behavior your observing where it doesn't matter what credentials you pass is due to your configuration. You've specifically configured the broker to allow "guest" users (i.e. users with bad credentials or no credentials) via your `login.config`:

```
   org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.GuestLoginModule sufficient
       debug=false
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.guest.user="admin"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.guest.role="amq";
```

You can read more about this login module in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html#guestloginmodule).

If you don't want to allow "guest" users then you can change `login.config` to be:

```
activemq {
   org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule required
       debug=false
       reload=true
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="artemis-users.properties"
       org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.role="artemis-roles.properties";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When the client creates the session, the broker tries to authenticate the client with the passed username and password.

Your `login.config` file contains 2 login modules `PropertiesLoginModule` and `GuestLoginModule`. If `PropertiesLoginModule` fails the login because of a wrong username/password the `GuestLoginModule` will login the user `admin` with the role `amq` as defined in your `login.config` file.

Answer (score 0):

Considering a standard installation (5.16.3), when you extract the archive you will find a conf folder.

Starting from there as a base for a Docker container, i had a hard time to configure ActiveMQ security, as there are multiple files involved which partly did not work as expected.
I assume i did not configure everything correctly, as changing login.config had basically no effect.

The only way i got security working was

- change jetty-realm.properties for the admin web page access
- change activemq.xml for broker security config

(Solution for activemq.xml was found [here](https://philipp-boss.de/blog/2013/07/activemq-simple-authentication-for-consumers-and-producers/))

Example config snippet for broker security:

```
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">
    
    <plugins>
        <simpleAuthenticationPlugin anonymousAccessAllowed="false">
            <users>
                <authenticationUser username="admin" password="admin1234!" groups="admins,senders,receivers"/>
                <!---<authenticationUser username="user" password="password" groups="users"/>
                <authenticationUser username="guest" password="password" groups="guests"/>-->
            </users>
        </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
        <authorizationPlugin>
            <map>
                <authorizationMap>
                    <authorizationEntries>
                        <authorizationEntry queue=">" write="senders" read="receivers" admin="admins" />
                    <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" write="senders" read="receivers" admin="admins,senders,receivers" />
                    </authorizationEntries>
                </authorizationMap>
            </map>
        </authorizationPlugin>
    </plugins>
    .
    .
```

This finally enabled security for Queue access.